# Mock injection in Spring using Spock not working

Tags: spring, mocking, spock, spring-retry

So I am using the `Spring=Retry` library in my project and trying to run a test case for that. 
I am loading the service DCS as a bean that returns a new object.
Its two dependencies SSService and AttributeService are loaded as beans as well. But these two are mocks.
When my test spec runs i can see inside DCS.execute that the mocks are there alright. But the interactions on them like `1 *  SSService.read(_ as LComponent,_) >> mockSimpleSettingCommResult` is not taking effect resulting in a null value instead of the value i want it to return.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [SpringRetryConfig])
class DCSISpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    DCS  DCS
    @Autowired
    SSService sSService
    @Autowired
    AttributeService attributeService

    def setup() {
//        DCS.SSService = SSService
//        DCS.attributeService = attributeService
    }

    def "execute failure"(){
        setup:
        DataCollectionDataSet mockDataCollectionDataSet = Mock(DataCollectionDataSet)
        LComponent mockLComponent = Mock(LComponent)
        SSCommResult mockSimpleSettingCommResult = Mock(SSCommResult)

        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(DCS, "SSService", SSService)
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(DCS, "attributeService", attributeService)

        when:
        DCS.execute(mockLComponent, mockDataCollectionDataSet)

        then:
        1 *  mockSimpleSettingCommResult.getDegreeOfSuccess() >> SSCommResult.DegreeOfSuccess.FAILURE
        1 * mockDataCollectionDataSet.getNamespace() >> DCSNamespace.xyz
        1 * mockDataCollectionDataSet.getDataElements() >> ["FOO": "BAR"]
        1 *  SSService.read(_ as LComponent,_) >> mockSimpleSettingCommResult

        3 * DCS.execute(_ as LComponent, _ as DataCollectionDataSet)
    }
    @Configuration
    @EnableRetry
    public static class SpringRetryConfig {
        @Bean
        public SSService SSService() {
            Mockito.mock(SSService)
        }
        @Bean
        public AttributeService attributeService() {
            Mockito.mock(AttributeService)
        }
        @Bean
        public DCS  DCS() {
           return new DCS();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exception i get when trying to use plain Mockito ,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
    at com.lexmark.mps.cma.service.DataCollectionRetryTest.test_retry(DataCollectionRetryTest.groovy:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to configure Spock interactions on `Mockito`s mock of `SSService`. It doesn't not work that way. Moreover, you misspelled `sSSservice` (you have `SSSservice`) in that interaction

Comment: And finally, you can't test retry by configuring interaction on a real object, `3 * DCS.execute...` in your case. Just mock it so that the first calls cause retry and final call is successful. Then check the number of calls

Comment: @DmitryKhamitov  Can you please point me to an example of a spring retry test using spock ? I am having a hard time  doing the retry tests through Spock. To top it our project uses Spock 0.7 which is quite old.

Comment: I know there is already an accepted answer, but the question is about Spock, so I would like to know why you use Mockito at all if you could just use Spock mocks. If that is an option, would you be interested in a Spock solution or are you just migrating away from Spock towards JUnit?

Comment: I understand your point. I have yet to find a better way to do it using Spock. But if I am able to find one i will add a new answer myself. For now I am using JUNit4 and Mockito to do this.   And yes if there is a Spock option i would take that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given my comments to the question above, I think you are better off using bare Mockito here (w/o Spock as you asked in the comments as I'm struggling on how to make a readable Spock specification for this use case):

**EDIT:** The completely correct solution is below this one

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DCSTest.SpringRetryConfig.class)
public class DCSTest {
    @Autowired
    private DCS dcs;

    @Test
    public void test_retry() {
        //given:
        LComponent component = mock(LComponent.class);
        DataCollectionDataSet dataSet = mock(DataCollectionDataSet.class);

        given(dcs.execute(component, dataSet)) //It's BDDMockito class
                .willThrow(new RuntimeException("1"))
                .willThrow(new RuntimeException("2"))
                .willReturn("Foo");

        //when:
        String result = dcs.execute(component, dataSet);

        //then:
        verify(dcs, times(3)).execute(component, dataSet);
        assertThat(result, equalTo("Foo"));
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableRetry
    static class SpringRetryConfig {
        @Bean
        DCS dcs() {
            return mock(DCS.class);
        }
    }
}

public class DCS {
    @Retryable(maxAttempts = 3)
    String execute(LComponent component, DataCollectionDataSet dataSet) {
        return "Bar";
    }
}
```

**CORRECT SOLUTION:**

Ok, as the OP and discovered the above `verify(dcs, times(3)).execute(component, dataSet);` doesn't work as expected. No matter what number you use in `times()` the test will always succeeds. This is because `@Retryable` creates an aspect around the `dcs` mock. As a result, each call to `dcs.execute` is intercepted by Spring and Mockito doesn't actually verify the call. To overcome this, we can create our own aspect around the mock and just as a side effect, count how many times the `@Retryable` method is called. Below is the working code of such a solution:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class DCSTest {
    @Autowired
    private LComponent component;
    @Autowired
    private DataCollectionDataSet dataSet;
    @Autowired
    private DCS dcs;
    @Autowired
    private RetryCount retryCount;

    @Test
    public void test_retry() {
        //when:
        String result = dcs.execute(component, dataSet);

        //then:
        assertThat(retryCount.value, equalTo(3));
        assertThat(result, equalTo("Foo"));
    }

    @Aspect
    public static class RetryCount {
        public int value = 0;

        @Before("execution(* DCS.execute(..))")
        public void advice() {
            value++;
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableRetry
    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
    public static class SpringRetryConfig {
        @Bean
        DCS dcs() {
            DCS dcs = mock(DCS.class);
            given(dcs.execute(component(), dataSet())) //It's BDDMockito class and take note that better to keep this declaration here so that Spring doesn't intercept the call once Retryable aspect is created
                    .willThrow(new RuntimeException("1"))
                    .willThrow(new RuntimeException("2"))
                    .willReturn("Foo");
            return dcs;
        }

        @Bean
        RetryCount retryCount() {
            return new RetryCount();
        }

        @Bean
        LComponent component() {
            return new LComponent();
        }

        @Bean
        DataCollectionDataSet dataSet() {
            return new DataCollectionDataSet();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I am doing this with Mock objects(using Mockito) for LComponent and DataCollectionDataSet and i keep getting a method invocation exception.

Comment: I've edited my answer so it uses `Mockito.mock` for `LComponent` and `DataCollectionDataSet`. It works for me. Have you tried the same setup? Can you provide a snippet of the stack trace you see in the error? Just 2-3 lines down from the invocation exception incl. would be fine

Comment: I have updated the trace in the last part of the question. Please note when i rujn from the debugger i get it at the line with `given` .

Comment: hm, do you run the exact code as in the answer? Because, I've tried different cases but couldn't achieve the same stack trace

Comment: Yeah it is the same thing I am running. I have JUnit 4.12, Mockito 1.10 , Spring boot 1.2 and spring 4.3.x

Comment: Which version of Groovy do you use? I've tried with the same config as yours except I have Groovy 2.5.0. And it works. Try creating java class instead of groovy one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188347/discussion-between-som-bhattacharyya-and-dmitry-khamitov).